# How to factorize common tags with nokogiri builder?

Tags: xml, ruby, nokogiri

I'd like to create several builders, with common tags, in order to have xml docs like :

```
  <xml version="1.0"?>
    <a_kind_of_root>
      <!-- This part is common -->
      <event_date>20100514</event_date>
      <event_id>123</event_id>
      <event_type>Conference</event_type>
      <!-- This part is specific to the builder -->
      <my_tag>some text</my_tag>
    </a_kind_of_root>
  </xml>

  <xml version="1.0"?>
    <another_kind_of_root>
      <!-- This part is common -->
      <event_date>20100514</event_date>
      <event_id>123</event_id>
      <event_type>Conference</event_type>
      <!-- This part is specific to the builder -->
      <my_other_tag>some integer</my_other_tag>
    </another_kind_of_root>
  </xml>
```

I don't know how to put the common part inside a Nokogiri::XML::Builder

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your Builder to a method & have that method add your common event information:

```
def event_tags(xml, ev=Hash.new)
  xml.event_date = ev[:date]
  xml.event_id = ev[:id]
  xml.event_type = ev[:type]
end

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    event_tags xml, :date => get_date, :id => get_id, :type => get_type
    # blah blah
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day!
Indeed, I try everything except that... Need some sleep.